# return handle in Android or some other systems

Tags: android, c++, c, linux

When I went through Android source codes and some system calls in Linux,

I found some functions keep mentioning the "handle" thing.

Like this function returns `a handle`.

By the meaning of handle, I dont clearly know what this means.

Does this mean `a pointer` ?

Can anyone explain this in detail? (Better with an example)

Comment: A "handle" is usually a so-called black box, it's private data that you should not peek at. It's often implemented as a pointer, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind to provide an example? (btw, would you mind to reply this quesiton in answer? so that I can accept your answer.)